# jquery selector parent to children issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
    <form data-v-c4600f50="" novalidate="novalidate" class="v-form">
        <div data-v-c4600f50="" class="pr-2" question="Top Secret4">
            <div data-v-c4600f50="" feid="FeLabel" class="theme--light v-label fe-label">
                <!---->Top Secret Mode</div>
            <div data-v-99d06acc="" data-v-c4600f50="" class="v-input fe-switch theme--light v-input--selection-controls v-input--switch">
                <div class="v-input__control">
                    <div class="v-input__slot">
                        <div class="v-input--selection-controls__input">
                            <input aria-checked="false" id="input-211" role="switch" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" feid="FeSwitch" value="">
                                <div class="v-input--selection-controls__ripple"/>
                                <div class="v-input--switch__track theme--light"/>
                                <div class="v-input--switch__thumb theme--light">
                                    <!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                            <div class="v-messages__wrapper"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the div that has v-input--selection-controls__input as a class in the above code with the following jquery:
`$( ":contains('Top Secret Mode')").parent().last().first().first().first()`

It seems to select the `<div data-v-c4600f50="" class="pr-2">` div instead though and I am not sure why.

Comment: There is only one parent... So `.last().first().first().first()` squarely does nothing. Try with [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) `$( ":contains('Top Secret Mode')").parent().find(".v-input--selection-controls__input")`

Comment: I wonder why can't you select element directly by class? However, instead of using parent(), better use siblings() and children() methods

Answer (score 0):

[.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) and [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) are sibling selectors. From the code you've provided, the parent of `Top Secret Mode` doesn't have any siblings, so it returns itself. You may want the [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method here.

```
$( ":contains('Top Secret Mode')").parent().find('.v-input--selection-controls__input')
```